# Conjugate directions and Krylov subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-optimization

I am reading about conjugate directions from [here](https://books.google.gr/books?id=wfs-hsrd4WQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Algorithm 5.1.1). The algorithm is

> Given $r_0$, set $p_0=-r_0$ and for $k=0,1,\dots,$ perform the
> iteration  $$a_k = ||r_k||^2 / \langle p_k, Hp_k \rangle\tag{1}$$ $$r_{k+1} =
>  r_k + a_k H p_k\tag{2}$$ $$\beta_k = ||r_{k+1}||^2/||r_{k}||^2\tag{3}$$ $$p_{k+1} = -r_{k+1} + \beta_k p_k\tag{4}$$

I the reference, it is stated that $$\mathcal{K}(H, r_0,j)=\text{span} \{ p_0, \dots, p_j\}=\text{span} \{ r_0, \dots, r_j\}\tag{5}$$ where $\mathcal{K}(H, r_0,j)$ is the Krylov subspace. Could you please someone explain how can be get the last equality using the update rules in the algorithm?

**EDIT:**

For the equivalence $\mathcal{K}(H, r_0,j)=\text{span} \{ r_0, \dots, r_j\}$ from $(2)$ and $p_0 = -r_0$ we have

$$r_1 = r_0 - a_0 H r_0 \in \text{span} \{ r_0, Hr_0\}.$$ Similarly, using this with $(2)$ $(3)$ ,and $p_0 = -r_0$

$$\begin{aligned}r_2 = &r_1 + a_1 Hp_1 = (r_0 -a_0 Hr_0) + a_1 H(-r_1 + \beta_0 p_0)  \\ = & \dots = r_0 - (a_0 + a_1+a_1\beta_0)Hr_0 -a_1 a_0 H^2 r_0 \in \text{span} \{ r_0, Hr_0, H^2r_0\}\end{aligned} $$

Then recursively, we get $r_j \in \text{span} \{ r_0, Hr_0, H^2r_0, \dots, H^jr_0\} \in \mathcal{K}(H, r_0,j)$. Following a similar procedure, we can show that $p_j \in \text{span} \{ r_0, Hr_0, H^2r_0, \dots, H^jr_0\} \in \mathcal{K}(H, r_0,j)$. How do we proceed to prove $(5)$?

Comment: Do you see how to prove the second equality?

Comment: @blamethelag thanks for the interest, I tried to replace $(2)$ in $(4)$ but thinks got more complicated.

Comment: @blamethelag proved the first part of the proof. The second part can be found in Theorem 5.3 [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/num_optimization.pdf). Thus I consider this post answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just prove $span \{ p_0,...,p_j \} = span \{ r_0,...,r_j \}$. By (4) I have for any $k \in [0..j-1]$ that
$$
r_{k+1} = \beta_k p_k - p_{k+1} \in span \{ p_0,...,p_j \}
$$
and
$$
r_0 = -p_0 \in span \{ p_0,...,p_j \}
$$
which yields the inclusion in the opposite direction. For the direct direction, we have for any $k \in [0..j-1]$
$$
p_{k+1} = -r_{k+1} + \beta_k p_k\in span \{ r_{k+1},p_k \}
$$
so by induction
$$
p_{k+1} \in span \{ r_{k+1},p_k \} \subset span \{ r_{k+1},r_k, p_{k-1} \} \subset ... \subset span \{ r_{k+1},r_k, ..., r_0\}.
$$
Re using $r_0 = -p_0$ we have the inclusion in the direct direction.

Comment: Thanks for your post. May I ask why $r_{k+1} = \beta_k p_k - p_{k+1} \in span \{ p_0,...,p_j \}$ and not $r_{k+1} \in span \{ p_k, p_{k+1} \} $?

Comment: @darkmoor what you say is exactly what I used to infer what I claim!

Comment: You mean that $r_{k+1} \in \text{span} \{ p_k, p_{k+1}\} \subset \text{span} \{ p_0, \dots, p_j\} \Rightarrow r_{k+1} \in \text{span} \{ p_0, \dots, p_j\}$?

Comment: I mean $r_{k+1} \in span \{ p_k,p_{k+1} \} \subset span \{ p_0,...,p_j \}$

Comment: You refers inclusion on the direct and opposite direction, could you please explain a little more what do you mean by that? What is the intuition? Also how using this we get the equality of the spaces? I didn't catch it. Thanks again.

Comment: If you wanna show $A=B$ the direct direction inclusion is $A \subset B$ and the opposite direction inclusion is $B \subset A$. If you show those two inclusions you have proven $A=B$.

Comment: Thanks. So far we have $r_{k+1} \in span \{ p_0,...,p_j \}$. How is that used to get the opposite inclusion, i.e., $\text{span} \{ r_0, \dots, r_j\} \subset \text{span} \{ p_0, \dots, p_j\}$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The span operation is increasing for the inclusion and $span \circ span = span$.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more details on these two properties? I can not see how they can be used. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130013/discussion-between-blamethelag-and-darkmoor).